# Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the function below to calculate the age (in years) of people from birthdays dates (in european format DD/MM/YYYY) that are stored as text in Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields

```
function get_age($birthDate_old) {
    $birthDate = ($birthDate_old);
    return date_diff(new DateTime($birthDate), new DateTime('today'))->y;
}
```

In the majority of cases it works fine but in some cases I got the error below :

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (26/01/1958) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character in /home/XXXX/functions.php:99 Stack trace: #0 /home/XXXX/functions.php(99): DateTime->__construct('26/01/1958') #1 /home/XXXX/single.php(69): get_age('26/01/1958') #2 /home/XXX/wp-includes/template-loader.php(98): include('/home/XXX/...') #3 /home/XXX/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/XXX/...') #4 /home/XXX/index.php(17): require('/home/monmaire/...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/XXXX/functions.php on line 99
```

Example of data that works fine : 
       $age = get_age($birthday);

For $birthday value = 05/04/1946 it works fine but for $birthday value = 26/01/1958 I get the error above.
I don't undertand why as the data seems to me the same format in the 2 cases.

Do you have any clue why ?

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix your function like this :

```
function get_age($birthDate_old) {
    return date_diff(
        DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $birthDate_old), 
        new DateTime('today')
    )->y;
}
```

In your case your date is malformated since DateTime constructor doesn't know if you pass a month or a day.

**05**/04/1946 is ok.

**26**/01/1958 is not ok because 26 represent month by default.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works fine. I did not know fact that DateTime was expected a specific format of date.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

```
// THIS IS INVALID, WOULD IMPLY MONTH == 19
$external = "19/10/2016 14:48:21";

// HOWEVER WE CAN INJECT THE FORMATTING WHEN WE DECODE THE DATE
$format = "d/m/Y H:i:s";
$dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $external);

$iso_datetime = $dateobj->format(Datetime::ATOM);
echo "SUCCESS: $external EQUALS ISO-8601 $iso_datetime";
```

26 is treated as month. So, add `$format = "d/m/Y";` to your date like above.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the date format. I believe you are switching between "/" and "-". If you are dealing with large data, it will be difficult to have to fix the whole database so my best advise is to do a preg_replace in order to always make sure what you are taking from the user/DB is in a correct format. Find example code below.

```
function get_age($birthDate_old) {
    $birthDate = ($birthDate_old);
    return date_diff(new DateTime($birthDate), new DateTime('today'))->y;
}


$birthDate = "26/01/1958";
$birthDate = preg_replace("(/)", "-", $birthDate);

echo get_age($birthDate);
```

I hope it helps! Let me know